# Shortest paths excluding one node

Tags: neo4j, cypher, shortest-path

I am working on a query on the movie database to check the shortest paths between n nodes. In this simplified example, we want all the shortest paths between 2 movies:

`match p=allShortestPaths((n)-[*]-(m)) where id(n) = 87 and id(m) = 121
return p;`

[image: all]

Now I want to have all the shortest paths that don't include Keanu Reeves in it.
I tried this:

`match p=allShortestPaths((n)-[*]-(m)) where id(n) = 87 and id(m) = 121 and NONE(n in nodes(p) where n.name = "Keanu Reeves")
return p;`

This however takes an eternity to load, even after I have indexed the name field of Person...

Then In tried the following:

`match p=allShortestPaths((n)-[*]-(m)) where id(n) = 87 and id(m) = 121
with p WHERE NONE(n in nodes(p) where n.name = "Keanu Reeves")
return p;`

This however gives me no results. I misinterpreted this by thinking it would just return those paths which don't have Keanu Reeves in between:

`(no changes, no records)`

I tested if I could get only those with Keanu Reeves in between with the `any()` function. This works perfectly:

`match p=allShortestPaths((n)-[*]-(m)) where id(n) = 87 and id(m) = 121
with p WHERE ANY(n in nodes(p) where n.name = "Keanu Reeves")
return p;`

[image: any()]

What is the best approach to tackle this? I must say that my production query is way more complex than this, but it all boils down to this problem. It has to be a performant solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that if one of the nodes from the path does not have the property `name`, then the entire check will not be passed.

So or do we check for [the existence of a property](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/where/#property-existence-checking):

```
match p=allShortestPaths((n)-[*]-(m)) 
where 
    n.title = 'The Replacements' and 
    m.title = 'Speed Racer' and
    NONE(n in nodes(p) where EXISTS(n.name) and n.name = "Keanu Reeves")
return p
```

Or use the [`COALESCE`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/scalar/#functions-coalesce) function:

```
match p=allShortestPaths((n)-[*]-(m)) 
where 
    n.title = 'The Replacements' and 
    m.title = 'Speed Racer' and
    NONE(n in nodes(p) where COALESCE(n.name, '') = "Keanu Reeves")
return p
```

Comment: This is exactly what's going on. Thanks! Would you recommend the `EXISTS()` or `COALESCE` approach?

Comment: @ValentinGrégoire I think that there is no difference.

Comment: You might also use a filter like replace(n.name,'Keanu Reeves','')<>n,name